# Can we pass ARG to CMD in DockerFile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

How can i pass ENV variable while using docker run command and also Can you tell me if i'm passing the ENV variable correctly in CMD?

Main thing which i want to achieve is that I have uploaded my code on gitlab and creating a docker image so that i can create my web application container. In that code we have a file Core.js which takes 2 arguments 1. Organization name and Port number. For that i need to run node Core.js Org1 1401, node Core.js  Org2 1402, etc.  There is a shell script which is pulled in via docker file i need to give name of that file as an argument so that it should use same docker image but i can create multiple container for different organization

```
FROM alpine

LABEL MAINTAINER "CoE"
WORKDIR /

ARG proxy
ARG username
ARG pswd
ENV ORG_SCRIPT

RUN export http_proxy=$proxy                                                                    && \
    export https_proxy=$proxy                                                                   && \
    git clone -b master https://$username:$pswd@git.devops.company.net/dlr_ui         && \
    npm install                     

 EXPOSE 1401 1402 1403 1404 1405 1406 1407 1408
 WORKDIR /applications/package/ui_servers 
CMD ["sh","./${ORG_SCRIPT}"]    // It is not getting the script name over here. Can you tell if it is correct way or not. OR i should do:
CMD ["sh","./$ORG_SCRIPT"]

I'm getting error for both. Value is not coming to that variable.

Buid:
 docker build --no-cache --build-arg proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg username=dfadf--build-arg pswd=dsfadsf --build-arg -t uinodetest .


RUN:
docker run  -d -it -p 1401:1401 -e ORG_SCRIPT runOrg1.sh --name="Org1_UI" uinodetest

OR Other method i'm using is

FROM alpine

LABEL MAINTAINER "CoE"
WORKDIR /

ARG proxy
ARG username
ARG pswd
ENV ORG_NAME
ENV ORG_PORT

RUN export http_proxy=$proxy                                                                    && \
    export https_proxy=$proxy                                                                   && \
    git clone -b master https://$username:$pswd@git.devops.company.net/dlr_ui         && \
    npm install                     

 EXPOSE 1401 1402 1403 1404 1405 1406 1407 1408
 WORKDIR /applications/package/ui_servers 
CMD ["node","Core.js","$ORG_NAME","ORG_PORT"]



Buid:
 docker build --no-cache --build-arg proxy=$http_proxy --build-arg username=dfadf--build-arg pswd=dsfadsf --build-arg -t uinodetest .


RUN:
docker run  -d -it -p 1401:1401 -e ORG_NAME ORG1 -r ORG_PORT 1401 --name="Org1_UI" uinodetest
```

Tell me if i'm missing something or my syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Docker will pass the environment variable to your container, but you need a shell to parse the `${var}` syntax into that variable. You got close with:

```
CMD ["sh","./${ORG_SCRIPT}"]
```

I suspect the reason this didn't work is because the arg passed to `sh` hasn't been expanded yet, and sh isn't processing that arg, it's just running it. Instead you need:

```
CMD ["sh","-c","./${ORG_SCRIPT}"]
```

That is almost exactly the same as the string/shell syntax, which I'd recommend instead:

```
CMD ./${ORG_SCRIPT}
```

Comment: but problem what i'm facing with this is that it is giving error:    "./\${ORG_SCRIPT} not found it is not passing value to this variable.

Comment: arguments are only avalible during build. At the time of running the command its gone. We would need to have a way to use them like macros, that why Im here searching if its possible.

Comment: In the OPs example, they passed those specific values as environment variables, not build args.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of moving parts here.

For the things that need to be configurable, it's probably easiest to refer to them using `process.env` in Node and *not* pass them as command-line arguments.  In your second example, refer to `process.env.ORG_NAME`, for example.

Some things don't need to be configurable.  In your second example, you can pick a fixed TCP port for your service; even if you use the Express default port 3000, you can `docker run -p 1401:3000`, `docker run -p 1402:3000`, *etc.* to assign different ports to different containers running the same image.  In your first example, you're trying to use an environment variable to specify the entire command; don't bother doing this and just use the standard Docker command line.

That would give you a routine Dockerfile like

```sh
FROM node:alpine
# Generally don't "git clone" in a Dockerfile.
WORKDIR /dlr_ui
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["node", "Core.js"]
```

And you don't need to worry about this particular problem at all.  You'd run it like

```
docker run -d -p 1401:3000 -e ORG_NAME=ORG1 --name="Org1_UI" uinodetest
```

There are two syntaxes for the CMD, ENTRYPOINT, and RUN commands.  The form that looks like a JSON array (but isn't actually) directly runs the command that's given, without invoking any kind of shell or interpreter or variable expansion.  In your second example the script will be invoked with the literal strings `$ORG_NAME` and `ORG_PORT` as parameters.  If you just write something that looks like a command, not using the JSONish syntax, it gets automatically wrapped in `sh -c`.

I would expect, syntactically, that the first example does what you want (but see @BMitch's answer); but it would be simpler to just pass the command directly

```
docker run -d -p 1401:1401 --name="Org1_UI" uinodetest ./runOrg1.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer it is running in this way but if when i'm creating a docker-compose file i.e the .yaml file and trying to run it it is getting exited.    I have created a yaml file version: '2' services: Uinode: image: uinodetest command: sh ./$testFile container_name: ORG_UI ports: - "1401:1401" environment: - FILE_NAME=$testFile and trying to run by shellscript: env=$1 docker-compose -f ui.yaml up -d and running it by ./test.sh uiOrg1.sh but it is creating a container which is getting exited within fraction of second without generating any log.

Comment: I have used forever start but still it is getting exited and script is running as nohup sh

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach would be using `ENTRYPOINT` and then add `CMD` to execute `help` or something similar

```
ENTRYPOINT ["node","Core.js"]
CMD ["--help"]
```

Then when you start the container pass the `$ORG_NAME` and `$ORG_PORT` to it. In this case docker will keep your entry point and overrides the default `CMD` which is `--help` in this case to the other options that you have passed and make sure to keep the command between quotes to be treated as single command

So in this case you will run the container as the following:

```bash
docker run -it --name my_container myimage:latest "$ORG_NAME $ORG_PORT"
```

> Same scenario can be done with docker compose.

Comment: I have created a yaml file version: '2' services:
  Uinode:
    image: uinodetest
    command: sh ./$testFile
    container_name: ORG_UI
    ports:
     - "1401:1401"
    environment:
     - FILE_NAME=$testFile                                                                                                                                  and trying to run by shellscript: env=$1 docker-compose -f ui.yaml up -d                                 and running it by ./test.sh uiOrg1.sh but it is creating a container which is getting exited within fraction of second without generating any log.

Comment: If you don't have any errors and the exit status is `0` then it could be because the script itself exited after completed the execution directory. In other words it should be running without exit for example when you run `node index.js` it wont exit unless you kill the process

Comment: yeah therefore i have used forever start but still it is getting exited and script is running as nohup sh